# Recursive function to get the parent caegory description

Tags: php, recursion, woocommerce

I have created a recursive function, and what i need is to get the parent category description and term_id of that product.

```
function desc_pro($parent) {
    $term = get_term_by('parent', $parent, 'product_cat');
    $description = $term->description;

    while($description == null) {
        $desc = desc_pro($term->parent);
        return $desc;
    }
    return $description;
}
```

Now when i run this code, i get the correct description.
But if i remove any of the return then it will not work. It shows blank. (This is okay? I think the code is wrong?)

Second: I need term_id and when i create the array, it send all the sub category ids as well. Which is wrong. I need just that id which has the description.

I think the code is wrong? Or there is any other problem?

This is the array with me: (what i send is the parent category from my php page. So i call 
function get_desc(48);)

It give me first object, now i have to test is description available or not?
If yes then stop and return description and it's term_id.
If it is not available then grab parent id and check again. So this continues, until description is found.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 48
    [name] => Cereal
    [slug] => cereal
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 49
    [taxonomy] => product_cat
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 46
    [count] => 0
)

stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 46
    [name] => Grocery Store A
    [slug] => grocery-store-a
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 47
    [taxonomy] => product_cat
    [description] => FDIC, 17th Street Northwest, Washington, DC
    [parent] => 45
    [count] => 0
)
```

Comment: if you remove the  `return` keywords the function will return nothing. can you be more clear on the second do you need all the sub category ids? because your `while` loop will run only once. your whole function will stop(return) when it get's to `return`

Comment: I think i have coded the function wrong.
Please see the object which i get, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your while loop doesn't change `$description` but `$desc`, it will always be `null` if it's not the base case and you have created an infinite loop.

Try this:

```
function desc_pro($parent) {
    $term = get_term_by('parent', $parent, 'product_cat');
    $description = $term->description;

    if( $description == null)
        return desc_pro($term->parent); // recurse if not set
        //$description = desc_pro($term->parent); // an alternative to the above

    return $description; // base case (when set)
}
```

The differences between the return and the assignment is the extra return. PHP doesn't do tail call optimization so it's not really that different, only that the one not commented out looks better for a functional programmer.

For an iterative approach a while loop would be good:

```
function desc_pro($parent) {
    $description = null;

    while( $description == null) {
        $term = get_term_by('parent', $parent, 'product_cat');
        $description = $term->description;
    }

    return $description; // base case (when set)
}
```

Comment: okay, so my code was correct if i use $description instead of $desc?

Comment: Also, according to this which one is good, if or while.
Both the code works for me now. :)

Comment: `if`, since it should not return without a decription. Also, a while loop would be good if you iterated instead of recursed. You would then repeat the two first lines in the while loop instead of recursing.

Comment: Also, can you tell me how to send just the particular description term_id, when i create a array, it gives me:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FDIC, 17th Street Northwest, Washington, DC
            [1] => 46
        )

    [1] => 48
)

And i do not need " [1] => 48 "

Comment: Okay, i am using if :)

But can you tell me about this array.

Comment: Thanks.. :).
Anyway, i figured about the array.

Comment: This only returns the description, eg. "FDIC, 17th Street Northwest, Washington, DC". To make an array with term_id and description you should have the base case looking like `return array( $term->term_id, $description);`